# d3d11.dll caused an Access Violation

Tags: unity-game-engine, directx, access-violation

So recently i downgraded to windows 7 from 10 for better performance. the game i wanted to play (clone hero) worked perfect on windows 10. after downgrading i got these "Access Violation" errors.. i tried disabling firewall and its a fresh install of windows 7. i only have chrome and clone hero installed.. sometimes it gives me AppHangB1 errors and sometimes it crashes before it reaches the splash screen saying "d3d11.dll caused an Access Violation"

I have tried installing all windows updates (i am on Windows 7 Home Basic SP1 64 bit)

(I have also tried updating my graphics card which i did not need to do on windows 10 to play the game)

```
Clone Hero [version: Unity 2017.3.1p2 (fd9fec26f216)]

d3d11.dll caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)
  in module d3d11.dll at 0033:f1aa1840.

Error occurred at 2019-07-06_201656.
C:\Users\Deagan\Desktop\oldch\Clone Hero.exe, run by Deagan.
36% memory in use.
3033 MB physical memory [1918 MB free].
6063 MB paging file [4841 MB free].
8388608 MB user address space [8388300 MB free].
Read from location 00000061 caused an access violation.

Context:
RDI:    0x040083a0  RSI: 0x00000000  RAX:   0x000f0060
RBX:    0x02506fe0  RCX: 0x000f0058  RDX:   0x00000000
RIP:    0xf1aa1840  RBP: 0x04145950  SegCs: 0x00000033
EFlags: 0x00010246  RSP: 0x002ff008  SegSs: 0x0000002b
R8:    0x00000000  R9: 0x00000000  R10:   0x00000000
R11:    0x002fedd0  R12: 0x00010800  R13:   0x00000001
R14:    0x00000002  R15: 0x00000000

Bytes at CS:EIP:
48 0f be 42 61 4c 8d 0d 4c 4f 02 00 48 83 c1 a8
```

I expected the game to run and not give AppHang or Access Violation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Access violation errors are generally due to a lack of permissions from what I've seen. Running the game specifically as administrator may solve the problem.